# How to do composite sprite on godot

Tags: sprite, godot, gdscript

I'm currently working on a 2 dimensional top down role playing game and i want to implement a equipment system wherein the way you look changes depending on the gear you have equipped and my idea is to do this by attaching the armor and weapons sprites onto the base sprite/composite sprite. I've been looking for tutorials on how i could implement this in Godot unfortunately the ones i see are only for unity so is this not possible on Godot? though if it is please tell me where i can learn it.

Comment: You could always make all the gear additions (sprites), children of the player sprite, and then toggle their visibility based on what the character is "carrying" or "wearing". However, the practicality of such a route would depend on how many additional "items" (sprites) that will be attached to the player. If there are alot, this might not be practical.

Comment: Expanding on Christoper's comment, if you did need a flexible number of sprites, you could build new sprite nodes on the fly and attach them as the player equips stuff. If these are equip slots, you could swap out the texture on a set number of sprite child nodes. Overall, we need more specifics to make informed answers. There are 100 ways to skin that cat.